# Хочу сделать табы на WP

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Хочу сделать табы на WordPress, но чтобы в самих табах была основная инфа, а когда нажать, то выезжает меню вниз.

Например, как тут [линк](http://www.zentis.ru/Proizvodstvo/Produkty-i-resheniya/Napolniteli-dlya-molochnyh-produktov).

Comment: А что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: У меня всё не выходит, я даже не знаю от чего отталкиваться, хочется наверное реализовать с помощью плагина, но я думаю, что можно сделать проще, чтобы выезжал другой ряд, по клику с другого ряда. Использую Visual composer

Comment: Если данный участок динамично будет обновляться для множества страниц, то пишите плагин. С чего начать - есть масса статей в сети по написанию структуры плагинов. Если интересует какой-то участок конкретный, в статичном виде, сделайте минимальную разметку, чтоб тому, кто решится вам помочь, не нужно было кучу лишней работы делать. А то скоро на SO вопросы будут выглядет так: "Мне вот так (ссылка на скрин)".

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev не будут, потому что это против правил. Предыдущий вопрос ТС был именно такого типа - его закрыли.